# Usage of grep correctly

Tags: bash, grep

I have 180 sub directories under main directory. I need to grep "Unresponse" in add_report.rpt file in all 180 sub-directories like below:

**tile#*t/PA*#_output/add_report.rpt**

where # represents tile1_t, tile2_t ...... tile180_t(because I am unable to use *)

I tried with this in the current directory:

```
grep -r "Unresponse"
```

But I am also getting from other sub-directories as well under tile#

Can anyone please help me with the correct way to grep. 
I only need the output from this path :

```
tile#_t/PA_#_output/add_report.rpt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `*` glob pattern to match any string. This is a bash feature and has nothing to do with `grep`:

```
grep 'Unresponse' tile*_t/PA_*_output/add_report.rpt
```